# Sharepoint access request is not being send

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, exchange, outgoing-email, requestaccessmail

I am administrate a SP-farm with multiple webApps. Outgoing e-mail is configured and works fine. There is only one exception - the access request mails. I found this

[Link to TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e6166b47-f9de-4d13-ac3f-0d49063b03cd/site-access-request-alerts-are-not-being-sent-to-specified-email?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Problem of all is, that every IP is already listed in exchange and the AUTH-mode is "anonymous", so there is no authentication required. The last few hours I tried to find something in the exchange logs or ULS but nothing. I also checked the quarantine and spam - nothing. I added the sender address as an exception in a rule - no mail.

And no, there is no AD group in the field for the receiver email. There is only one normal email address entered.

So... I don´t know how to get a step forward. Could anyone help me please?

Thanks for any effort!

Comment: are you saying your web apps are configured for anonymous access?

Comment: no, the exchange auth from inside of the network is anonymous. There is no auth required for the AppPoolAccount to send mails over exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I´ve got the answer. The anonymous rights are "not enough". You need to assign the rights for the receive connector the appPoolAccounts.

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same Issue, all E-Mail notifications were send out except Access Requests.

After a lot of debugging and log analysing, we found the Issue on the Exchange side. The Webapp Pool User needed Extended Rights on the Exchange Connectors.

The Rights that we needed to add:

- `Get-ReceiveConnector "" | Add-ADPermission -User "DOMAIN\AppPoolAccount" -ExtendedRights "ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Any-Sender"`
- `Get-ReceiveConnector "" | Add-ADPermission -User "DOMAIN\AppPoolAccount" -ExtendedRights "ms-Exch-SMTP-Accept-Authoritative-Domain-Sender"`
- `Get-ReceiveConnector "" | Add-ADPermission -User "DOMAIN\AppPoolAccount" -ExtendedRights "ms-Exch-SMTP-Submit"`